# Figure 7px taller than it should be

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why my rollovers for my figures are 7px taller than the figures themselves?

Been looking at this for nearly 2 hours and it's driving me towards insanity.

Note: This site is nowhere near finished so there is probably lots still wrong with it but if someone could tell me where the 7px is coming from that would be great.

I can post code if needed but here is a link to the test page.

[Link to the text site](http://www.soco-creative.co.uk/own-work/test/index.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Make a minimal test case and post it here. People don't want to debug your web page for you.

Comment: What browser are you viewing it in ?

Comment: @Dave - I disagree.  The issue is directly related to the HTML/CSS on the page.  While he could of been clearer on his question, the issue he is experiencing is easily replicated with the link he provided, and took a matter of seconds to solve.

Comment: Thanks guys. The answer below fixed it.

Comment: @Axel the ease of diagnosis isn't the point. The point is that this question will never help anybody else, because it hasn't been reduced to a minimal form, and future viewers will only understand it if that website is still live. In StackOverflow terminology, it is "too localised"

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  I see your point.

Comment: Dave, apologies. I'm not a regular Stack Exchange user. I Will try to phrase my questions better in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra space is actually a cause of `line-height`.  Since you are using `display: inline-block;` on `.portfolioWork figure`, line-height will have an affect on it.

Just add `line-height: 0;` to `.portfolioWork figure` and it will fix the issue.

Your CSS definition will look like this:

```
.portfolioWork figure {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Axel. Appreciate the help, you've saved me some hair! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think I would have ever figured out it was line-height causing my issue!